# How to cite papers that are in submission and don't have preprints?

Tags: citations

I'm writing a paper right now to soon be submitted to a workshop venue. The way the review process works for this particular workshop is that it's a "rolling review process," in that people publicy submit their work on OpenReview and receive feedback and a decision within a couple of weeks.

Due to the public nature of the submission process, everyone has access to the information of the work (PDF files of the manuscript, comments from anonymous reviewers containing feedback and decisions, etc.), and I've been fortunate to come across previous submissions and further tune my manuscript.

The predicament I'm facing is, when I cite these papers, how exactly should I go about it? Many of them don't appear on preprint servers like arXiv nor on Google Scholar. My initial thought is to just make the BibTeX file myself and fill in the relevant information (e.g., title, author, submitted date, URL), but I'm just not sure how to go about a work that's still under review and in submission.

I've asked other senior members at my lab, but was hoping that the community may be able to provide some other opinions or experiences. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to use the BibTeX provided by OpenReview, if available, and adapt it if necessary. A quick glance suggests that this is available for most submissions, including those that are anonymous or under review.

Screenshot for reference:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's also what I was planning on doing as it seems like the only reasonable way. Would there be any standard procedure for going about this process though?

Comment: @Seankala I don't know, but I think something to consider would be: (1) the reference should have all the information necessary to find the source (e.g. URL, if applicable), (2) since it is unpublished, if there is a chance that the paper can be removed / replaced, it might be good to include the date it was accessed. Utility of the reference probably matters more than the exact format. But maybe someone else will provide a better answer.